# How to add files to JList?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jlist

I am creating my GUI in NetBeans and I would need a help with JList. Every time I open some TXT file via JFileChooser I would like to add this file to the JList. How can I do it?

---

Thank you very much for your answers, but it doesn't work, I don't know why :(. However I wil ltry to explain my problem deeper, maybe it will help.

Here is the screenshot of my draft application -

[image]

What I want is to open TXT file a add it to the JList Layers (see on the picture). By this way I would like to add as many layers as the user wants. Then clicking on each Layer in the List I would like to visualize this layer in the panel Layer overview (JLabel). So my problem is - HOW TO STORE all the layers in the JList and then HOW TO ACCESS particular selected layer in order to visualize it.

I know  it is a bit weird from me to formulate it in this way but I will appreciate any help.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your predicament. Posting some code would be beneficial.

Comment: Get the model that the JList uses, and add the file to this.

Answer (score 0):

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();

int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(parent);
if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
JList list = new JList(model);
int pos = list.getModel().getSize();
model.add(pos, chooser.getSelectedFile());
```

Comment: Also, no need to add `String` objects to the list (especially when losing all but the name).  Better to add the `File` objects.

Comment: No need for the pos variable if you simply use DefaultListModel's `addElement(Object obj)` method. I have removed my down-vote.